# Persist variable sharing (Android)

Tags: java, android, operating-system, embedded-linux

Android comes up with some system variables like persist and ro which are present .props. Variable persist would retain its value after reboots. But is it possible that these variables are shared amongst two .img?

For example; if I have persist.test in system/build.prop (part of system.img) and the same variable is present in recovery/default.prop (part of recovery.img), is it possible that if I change persist.test in init.rc of recovery.img then this change is persistent and reflected when i try to getprop while device is booting normally?

Could anyone please help me understanding this?

Answer (score 0):

No that will not be the case.

The properties are managed by the android init process and it is in the system image or possible a separate init is present in your recovery image, but they are not shared.
See [this post](http://rxwen.blogspot.com.au/2010/01/android-property-system.html) had a bit more about the property service or see the excellent [Embedded Android book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do)